# How to edit Home.aspx on SharePoint site without SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I am a ASP.Net programmer and a newbie to SharePoint, I have the following questions:

1. From Sharepoint server admin where can I see the actual source code, folder path where all ASPX files are located with CS files
2. Sharepoint doesn't have.CS files.
3. My site looks like www.mysite.com/devserver/SitePages/Home.aspx
   Where is this home.aspx in which folder?
4. How do i edit this Home.aspx
5. I am using sharepoint 2010.
6. what is the database name that sharepoint uses.
7. How do i create a staging server for my sharepoint site.

Comment: Maybe there are other schools of thought, but I would not recommend editing the home.aspx page or any other provided aspx page.  Always make a copy and edit that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download SharePoint Designer (SPD) to view and edit source code, especially if your new to SharePoint or Web Development in general (other editors are way better, but this will get you started). It is [free](http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-SharePoint-Designer-2010-64-bit/3000-2064_4-75451285.html). All of your .ASPX pages are located at the "root" of your site (http:///sites/) and can be accessed with SPD. You don't need to worry about .CS files, unless you are developing a SP solution or app (now add-ins (I guess)).

SharePoint has two types of databases, which is your Configuration database that is created when you [install SharePoint on a server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607866(v=office.14).aspx) and Content databases that store content from your sites and Service Applications, etc. In order to access these databases, you have to have access to the SQL Server in your farm. **Remember this:** you never want to directly edit the databases.

Comment: Sorry, that should've been http://domain/sites/YourSiteName

Answer (score 0):

1. Home.aspx will likely be in the Site Pages library.
2. ?? I'm not a .net developer
3. You can create additional .aspx pages in the SitePages library and flag one of them as the new home page.
4. Site Settings >> Edit Page
5. Noted
6. It uses lots of databases.  The database your site is in will be defined in Central Admin.
7. We use a 3 tier environment.  New sites are created in dev in Visual Studio.  Sites are deployed via Farm Solution (.wsp) with all content into test to verify it was setup properly.  If not, back to dev.  If so, deploy in production.  Having 3 farms is expensive.